# Make a !!!Batch compiler/translator

Tags: code-golf, string, interpreter

!!!Batch is another derivative of the Windows Batch programming language, its wiki is [here](https://esolangs.org/wiki/!!!Batch)

Your challenge is to create an compiler/translator that reads a !!!Batch program and returns a Windows Batch program.

In !!!Batch each token braced in two question marks like `?!!!?` is converted to another ASCII character, like '?!?' -> 'a' and so on below, and after decoding the whole !!!Batch program it is a Windows batch program

```
'?!?', 'a'
'?!!?', 'b'
'?!!!?', 'c'
'?!!!!?', 'd'
'?!!!!!?', 'e'
'?!!!!!!?', 'f'
'?!!!!!!!?', 'g'
'?!!!!!!!!?', 'h'
'?!!!!!!!!!?', 'i'
'?!!!!!!!!!!?', 'j'
'?!!!!!!!!!!!?', 'k'
'?!!!!!!!!!!!!?', 'l'
'?!!!!!!!!!!!!!?', 'm'
'?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?', 'n'
'?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?', 'o'
'?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?', 'p'
'?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?', 'q'
'?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?', 'r'
'?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?', 's'
'?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?', 't'
'?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?', 'u'
'?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?', 'v'
'?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?', 'w'
'?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?', 'x'
'?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?', 'y'
'?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?', 'z'
'?!-?', '&'
'?!!-?', ' '
'?!!!-?', '?'
'?!!!!-?', '!'
'?!!!!!-?', '%'
'?!!!!!!-?', '/'
'?!!!!!!!-?', '.'
'?!!!!!!!!-?', ':'
'?!!!!!!!!!-?', '0'
'?!!!!!!!!!!-?', '1'
'?!!!!!!!!!!!-?', '2'
'?!!!!!!!!!!!!-?', '3'
'?!!!!!!!!!!!!!-?', '4'
'?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!-?', '5'
'?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!-?', '6'
'?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!-?', '7'
'?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!-?', '8'
'?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!-?', '9'
'?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!-?', '='
'?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!-?', '+'
'?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!-?', '-'
'?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!-?', '<'
'?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!-?', '>'
'?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!-?', '@'
'?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!-?', '*'
'?!+?', 'A'
'?!!+?', 'B'
'?!!!+?', 'C'
'?!!!!+?', 'D'
'?!!!!!+?', 'E'
'?!!!!!!+?', 'F'
'?!!!!!!!+?', 'G'
'?!!!!!!!!+?', 'H'
'?!!!!!!!!!+?', 'I'
'?!!!!!!!!!!+?', 'J'
'?!!!!!!!!!!!+?', 'K'
'?!!!!!!!!!!!!+?', 'L'
'?!!!!!!!!!!!!!+?', 'M'
'?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!+?', 'N'
'?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!+?', 'O'
'?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!+?', 'P'
'?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!+?', 'Q'
'?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!+?', 'R'
'?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!+?', 'S'
'?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!+?', 'T'
'?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!+?', 'U'
'?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!+?', 'V'
'?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!+?', 'W'
'?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!+?', 'X'
'?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!+?', 'Y'
'?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!+?', 'Z'
```

Example Input:

```
?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!??!!-??!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!??!!!!!!!-??!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!?
```

Example output:

```
ping google.com
```

**How the output?

First break down into parts:

```
?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!? -> 'p'
?!!!!!!!!!? - 'i'
```

and so on

- For more clarification, please visit the [Wiki](https://esolangs.org/wiki/!!!Batch) or ask me here.
- Standard loopholes apply
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest code wins

An un-golfed sample compiler in python 2, from the Wiki page

> ```
> s = open(raw_input("Run Script: "), 'r').read()
> s = s.replace('?!?', 'a')
> s = s.replace('?!!?', 'b')
> s = s.replace('?!!!?', 'c')
> s = s.replace('?!!!!?', 'd')
> s = s.replace('?!!!!!?', 'e')
> s = s.replace('?!!!!!!?', 'f')
> s = s.replace('?!!!!!!!?', 'g')
> s = s.replace('?!!!!!!!!?', 'h')
> s = s.replace('?!!!!!!!!!?', 'i')
> s = s.replace('?!!!!!!!!!!?', 'j')
> s = s.replace('?!!!!!!!!!!!?', 'k')
> s = s.replace('?!!!!!!!!!!!!?', 'l')
> s = s.replace('?!!!!!!!!!!!!!?', 'm')
> s = s.replace('?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?', 'n')
> s = s.replace('?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?', 'o')
> s = s.replace('?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?', 'p')
> s = s.replace('?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?', 'q')
> s = s.replace('?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?', 'r')
> s = s.replace('?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?', 's')
> s = s.replace('?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?', 't')
> s = s.replace('?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?', 'u')
> s = s.replace('?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?', 'v')
> s = s.replace('?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?', 'w')
> s = s.replace('?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?', 'x')
> s = s.replace('?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?', 'y')
> s = s.replace('?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?', 'z')
> s = s.replace('?!-?', '&')
> s = s.replace('?!!-?', ' ')
> s = s.replace('?!!!-?', '?')
> s = s.replace('?!!!!-?', '!')
> s = s.replace('?!!!!!-?', '%')
> s = s.replace('?!!!!!!-?', '/')
> s = s.replace('?!!!!!!!-?', '.')
> s = s.replace('?!!!!!!!!-?', ':')
> s = s.replace('?!!!!!!!!!-?', '0')
> s = s.replace('?!!!!!!!!!!-?', '1')
> s = s.replace('?!!!!!!!!!!!-?', '2')
> s = s.replace('?!!!!!!!!!!!!-?', '3')
> s = s.replace('?!!!!!!!!!!!!!-?', '4')
> s = s.replace('?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!-?', '5')
> s = s.replace('?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!-?', '6')
> s = s.replace('?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!-?', '7')
> s = s.replace('?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!-?', '8')
> s = s.replace('?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!-?', '9')
> s = s.replace('?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!-?', '=')
> s = s.replace('?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!-?', '+')
> s = s.replace('?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!-?', '-')
> s = s.replace('?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!-?', '<')
> s = s.replace('?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!-?', '>')
> s = s.replace('?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!-?', '@')
> s = s.replace('?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!-?', '*')
> s = s.replace('?!+?', 'A')
> s = s.replace('?!!+?', 'B')
> s = s.replace('?!!!+?', 'C')
> s = s.replace('?!!!!+?', 'D')
> s = s.replace('?!!!!!+?', 'E')
> s = s.replace('?!!!!!!+?', 'F')
> s = s.replace('?!!!!!!!+?', 'G')
> s = s.replace('?!!!!!!!!+?', 'H')
> s = s.replace('?!!!!!!!!!+?', 'I')
> s = s.replace('?!!!!!!!!!!+?', 'J')
> s = s.replace('?!!!!!!!!!!!+?', 'K')
> s = s.replace('?!!!!!!!!!!!!+?', 'L')
> s = s.replace('?!!!!!!!!!!!!!+?', 'M')
> s = s.replace('?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!+?', 'N')
> s = s.replace('?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!+?', 'O')
> s = s.replace('?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!+?', 'P')
> s = s.replace('?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!+?', 'Q')
> s = s.replace('?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!+?', 'R')
> s = s.replace('?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!+?', 'S')
> s = s.replace('?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!+?', 'T')
> s = s.replace('?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!+?', 'U')
> s = s.replace('?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!+?', 'V')
> s = s.replace('?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!+?', 'W')
> s = s.replace('?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!+?', 'X')
> s = s.replace('?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!+?', 'Y')
> s = s.replace('?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!+?', 'Z')
> print s
> ```

Comment: “each character “ sounds incorrect, can you say “each token” or something like that?

Comment: @user clarified it see edit

Comment: In !!!Batch each token braced in two question marks like ?!!!? is converted to another ASCII character, like '?!?' -> 'a' and so on below, and after decoding the whole !!!Batch program it is a Windows batch program

Comment: A suggestion: use “compiler” or “transpiler” instead of “interpreter”

Comment: I don't think this is an interpreter, looks more like a translator since it doesn't actually run anything.

Comment: @Razetime changed the title

Comment: Do you need any kind of more clarification?

Comment: 'd better including including the full description into the post, don't expect people to read the wiki.

Comment: What's the `-` for?

Comment: Is the input guaranteed to be valid?

Comment: @user202729 `?!!-?` resolves to a space: " ", please read the question properly

Comment: @user202729 input is guaranteed to be valid

Comment: The Python 2 example is wrong. For input `?!!!-??!!!!-??!!!!-??!!!!-??!!!!-??!!!!-??!!!!-??!!!!-??!!!!-??!!!!-??!!!!-??!!!!-??!!!!-??!!!!-??!!!!-??!!!!-??!!!!-??!!!!-??!!!!-??!!!!-??!!!!-??!!!!-??!!!!-??!!!!-??!!!!-??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!-??!!!-?` it should output `?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!-?` but instead it outputs `@`

Comment: Suggest to add any testcases with upper case letters.

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript, 118 bytes

```javascript
s=>s.replace(/.+?\?/g,x=>x[i=x.length-2]>','?'& ?!%/.:0123456789=+-<>@*'[i-2]:String.fromCharCode(x[i]<'+'?96+i:63+i))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY5BDoIwEEWvIgstWFoUFIVQxoQjuEQWBAvUICWFGG6PJBA2Jjir@S8vM/@VftI2U6LpSC2ffMjZ0LKwpYo3VZpx3aIYHmAVZs/CPhaspxWvi64kdhIiEwHabUDbWtQ/HG3ndHYvV49hEoS3PYrFKPn3Tom6oLmS76hMVTQ@0cdDSYAwAs/FwncdLAxjyGTdyorTShZ6riPQ5sEwrbCQf2kG5Ieu6uvSlBZGAI2Vvw)

---

## JavaScript, 118 bytes

```javascript
s=>s.replace(/.!+(.??)\?/g,(x,y)=>(i=x.length,y>','?'& ?!%/.:0123456789=+-<>@*'[i-4]:String.fromCharCode(61+i+33*!y)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY5LDoIwGISvIgttS2kRQXzE8ptwBJfqgmCBGqSmECOnRxKIGxOc1cyXSWbuySupU6OeDav0TXaZ6GoR1dzIZ5mkErvcopgDkAu4uYPfTktEhJV481JWeVM4bYQcBGgxA2vu8v3SW/nBOtxsd4KyQ3S00Vmx4Lo/NUZVOc@MfsRFYuJ@C4ceVdT3baslhHSprmpdSl7qHGcYgTWKwmDhS/6lEbAfOlmfLg3pyxig/vIH)

Quite trivial answer.

---

Thanks to [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld), changing `String.fromCharCode(n)` into `Buffer([n])` under Node.js environment may save 11 bytes and results [107 bytes](https://tio.run/##hY5BDoIwEEWvIgsdtLQoKAqhHeM1kAXBFmsIEEDD7ZEEwsYE/2r@y5vkv5JP0qS1rlpalA/ZK943XDSsllWepNK0GcE72pnVcdFFmncsl0XWPqkTC7AAYbNCY22zYH9w3OPJO198TmgorjuI9CAFt7dSsjaj4TkOgQD6HtGB5xIdb7d9WhZNmUuWl5mpTEBjCsHxxJn8axOgP3RRX5bGNjOKMEz@Ag).

Comment: You can use `Buffer([n])` instead of `String.fromCharCode(n)`.

Comment: @Arnauld I'm not familiar with Node. I just want to post an answer in JavaScript. And TIO helps me add "(Node.js)" in the language name. I will add the Buffer([n]) trick in the post body but keeps the submission as is (as pure javascript).

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 41 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
¬¡õKεθ„!+skADužh"& ?!%/.:ÿ=+-<>@*")ćèyć¢è
```

Output as a list of characters.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//0JpDCw9v9T639dyORw3zFLWLsx1dSo/uy1BSU7BXVNXXszq831Zb18bOQUtJ80j74RWVR9oPLTq84n@t1397RTRgb4@NicoHMXRReLiMwKIRQxguCDGSkHH2AA) (the footer is to join the resulting list to pretty-print as string; feel free to remove it to see the actual list output).

**Explanation:**

```python
¬             # Push the first character of the (implicit) input-string: "?"
 ¡            # Split the input on that character
  õK          # Remove all empty strings
    ε         # Map over each string:
     θ        #  Pop and push its last character
      „!+     #  Push string "!+"
         sk   #  Get the index of the last character in this string,
              #  (-1 if not found, for the "-")
     A        #  Push the lowercase alphabet
      Du      #  Create an uppercase copy
        žh    #  Push builtin "0123456789"
          "& ?!%/.:ÿ=+-<>@*"
              #  Push this string, where the `ÿ` is automatically filled with 0123456789
     )        #  Wrap all values into a list
      ć       #  Extract head; pop and push remainder-list and first item separated
       è      #  Use this index to (0-based modulair) index into the triplet
              #  (where the -1 for "-" will index into the last item)
        y     #  Push the current string again
         ć    #  Extract its head as well: "!"
          ¢   #  Count how many times it occurs in the remainder-string
           è  #  0-based index this into the string
              # (after the map, the resulting list of characters is output implicitly)
```

Unfortunately the `"& ?!%/.:0123456789=+-<>@*"` is a bit too irregular to compress. The shortest alternative I could find for this straight-forward string was `žQ33£S•1δÁεöI‡β₆¡ÙÞ‹f31•.I` (`žQ` push printable ASCII builtin; `33£` leave just its first 33 characters; `S` convert it from a string to a list of characters; `•1δÁεöI‡β₆¡ÙÞ‹f30•.I` get the 1586478393328926104294588200482791040th permutation of this list), which is 6 bytes longer.

Answer (score 3):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), <sup><s>53</s></sup> 46 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
é♫▼V0⌂Ä╟ì⌡(Φzf■£┘╔╣T╘K*╪☻w²¥íÑ╧zv-¼Ö╨◘P♦ε♦íäq*
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=820e1f56307f8ec78df528e87a66fe9cd9c9b954d44b2ad80277fd9da1a5cf7a762dac99d0085004ee04a184712a&i=%3F%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%3F%3F%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%3F%3F%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%3F%3F%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%3F%3F%21%21-%3F%3F%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%3F%3F%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%3F%3F%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%3F%3F%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%3F%3F%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%3F%3F%21%21%21%21%21%3F%3F%21%21%21%21%21%21%21-%3F%3F%21%21%21%3F%3F%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%3F%3F%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%3F)

I wasn't able to find an expression that matches the symbols, so those are hardcoded (and take a lot of space.)

### Explanation

`'?/{f{%_rh.-+I{"@*& ?!%/.:"Vd+"=+-<>"+@}{63+}{96+}3l@!m`

`'?/` split on `?`

`{f` remove empty lists

`{..m` map the strings to:

`%` push the length of the match

`_` push the match again

`rDh` get the second to last character

`.-+I` index of that in "-+"

`@!` execute the corresponding block for the index:

`{"<>@*& ?!%/.:"Vd+"=+-"+@}{61+}{94+}3l` create a list of 3 blocks

`{63+}` for `+`, add 63 to the length

`{"@*& ?!%/.:"Vd+"=+-<>"+@}` for `-`, index into `<>@*& ?!%/.:0123456789=+-` using the length(modular)

`{96+}` otherwise add 91

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>142</s> <s>139</s> <s>130</s> 115 bytes

Thanks to tsh for the -3 and gastropher for the -9.

The function uses a state machine to determine the boundaries of each token:

- loop: load the next input character until the end of the string
- state 0 (initial `?`): clear the counter, then go to state 1
- state 1 (`!`, `+`, `-` or terminating `?`): increment on a `!`, otherwise print the character (adjusted count by 96 [`?`] or 64 [`+`], or indexed symbol [`-`]) and go to state 0, incrementing the input string if a `+` or `-`.

```c
t,c,n;f(char*s){for(;c=*s++;)n=t?c-33?t=!putchar(c-63?s++,c-43?" & ?!%/.:0123456789=+-<>@*"[n]:n+64:n+96):n+1:t++;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZDBTsMwEETv/oqNEch24kJJCDSu635AxY1T1UO0IW2k4qDahUOVXyc4PSClQuDD6o1nPZYG5Rax732CiVU1w115EI6f6vbAFGrh4lhxq71BmabG6@j96IcdhjJPTXATlFlqKNyAia5vJ8Xd9D7NHvLHp5mO5XyxFHRtN4WN8yyMWc7DnBY@pHb9VWNxf6xeYe581bST3YKQxnp4KxvLPtqm4nAiAMN3INx6owcFQE10cYz5Dcd6AGnoOOFy@4@LsTMO@vHkmf5LNTQ5v35@Wa0CdAkI4RUJOLTutVMQNISmHaOUc6iZCI1xRbr@C@t9uXW9/PwG)

Comment: I believe, according to the rules, you can remove the `t=0` in `for(t=0;c=*s++;)` since we can assume global variable used in function will never be modified outside. Global variables are initialed to 0 by default. And the function reset to 0 after execute. So the function is still reusable without it.

Comment: [130 bytes](https://tio.run/##hZFNTsMwEEb3OcXUCOTf0pIQaNx0OEDFjlXVReSQNlJxUO3CosrVCU4WSKkQePW@mfGzNDZqZ0zXeWmk1RU1@@LIHTtXzZFqk3MnhGYevZqjz2eZUXGM7yffj1Gj0hi9ENKoJEYCN4CT69tpNpvfxcl9@vC4yIVarp442dhtZkWaZDRIpBWLlLFQEBm1IQcF0213VVtzOJWvsHS@rJvpfhVFtfXwVtSWfjR1yeAcAfRPA3ebbd4nAIKTi4P4G45zDwrJ2HA5/Udh3BmLfnpqoP@sSORw@/llvQ7QSuDc6yhg/wk@dxpChrB1RwlhDCrKh5VFbfdlqkOxc536/AY)

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), <s>94</s> 94 bytes

```
\?!
!
!\?
a
!\+\?
A
-

!{5}\?
%
+T`_o`lL%/.:d=+\-<>@*!_`!(?![?!]).
!\?
$& &
!(?=..(.))!*...
$1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P8/xl6RCwhj7LkSgaQ2kHbk0uXiUqw2rQWyVbm0QxLi8xNyfFT19axSbLVjdG3sHLQU4xMUNewVo@0VYzX1wJpV1BTUuIBitnp6Gnqamopaenp6XCqG///bK6IBe3tsTFQ@iKGLwsNlBBaNGMJwQYiRhIyzBwA) Edit: +1 byte to fix a bug but -1 thanks to @tsh. Explanation:

```
\?!
!
```

Remove the `?` at the start of a token.

```
!\?
a
```

`?!?`, which is now `!?`, translates to `a`.

```
!\+\?
A
```

`?!+?`, which is now `!+?`, translates to `A`.

```
-
```

Get rid of the `-`s.

```
!{5}\?
%
```

`?!!!!!-?`, which is now `!!!!!?`, translates to `%`.

```
+T`_o`lL%/.:d=+\-<>@*!_`!(?![?!]).
```

For each additional `!`, cycle the following character; letters get incremented, while `d` represents digits which nestle among the symbols.

```
!\?
$& &
```

The remaining `!?`s represent one of `!`, `?`,   and `&` in reverse order, depending on the number of preceding `!`s. Add the other characters so that the correct decode can be selected.

```
!(?=..(.))!*...
$1
```

Decode the remaining `!?`, `!!?`, `!!!?` and `!!!!?` sequences appropriately.

Comment: `!+\?` should be `!\+\?` (+1 byte), but `!!!!!\?` may be `!{5}\?` (-1 byte).

Answer (score 3):

## [Julia](http://julialang.org/), <sup><s>108</s> <s>104</s></sup> 102 bytes

-4 bytes thanks to [tsh](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/44718/tsh)'s better regex

```julia
s->replace(s,r".+?\?"=>x->(a='.'-x[(l=end)-1];["_& ?!%/.:0123456789=+-<>@*_"[l-2],l+'^',l+'='][a%11]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVFhT8MgFPzeX/FKMoG1VOnc1Cmw/8HYQmqbYLAunSb8@wo1aqYzXvLg3uXekTye3ryzPIydGI9MDu3B26Ylx3JAVaG2CgkZmCRW4AqzoIkXbf9IGTf3Gu0vQOWzy2p9xevF9XJ1c3snCvYgN/M90p7VpvQF3uF0Cmy0nXFuKB0Pg@tffU86glT@A0qdo6d9Iuyk@yvizOAv@Uv8iPwvTiFKs6x7GYA0pXu2gYLrQaO4p3pVAmKJLCMpJsVkEJHsLvn4Oo1M2oQAApBCMAec452LdxMrKt@Wz21Fq4SOhPh8kuMvZLHGdw)

Comment: I don't know Julia, but maybe use regex `r".+?\?"` replace `r"\?!+.*?\?"` may helpful to your solution.

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-n`, <s>96</s> <s>84</s> 83 bytes

```perl
say map/-/?substr'  & ?!%/.:0123456789=+-<>@*',y///c,1:chr/!$/*32+64+y///c,/[^?]+/g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVIhN7FAX1ffvrg0qbikSF1BQU3BXlFVX8/KwNDI2MTUzNzC0lZb18bOQUtdp1JfXz9Zx9AqOaNIX1FFX8vYSNvMRBsiqh8dZx@rrZ/@/7@9Ihqwt8fGROWDGLooPFxGYNGIIQwXhBhJyDj7f/kFJZn5ecX/dX1N9QwMDf7r5gEA)

Answer (score 3):

## Batch <s>1139</s> <s>1034</s> <s>1009</s> 975 bytes.

*Ouch!* Though I couldn't resist making a batch !!!batch translator.

```bat
@Echo off&Set $=Set &Set _=%*
%$%_=%_:??=? ?%
%$%"_=%_:!=^!%"&%$%".=!!!!"
%$%"..=%.%%.%"
%$%"...=%..%%..%"
%$%?!-?=^&&%$%"?!!-?= "&%$%?!!!-?=?&%$%"?%.%-?=^!"&%$%"?%.%!-?=%%"&%$%?%.%!!-?=/
%$%?%.%!!!-?=.&%$%?%..%-?=:&%$%?%..%!-?=0&%$%?%..%!!-?=1&%$%?%..%!!!-?=2&%$%?%..%%.%-?=3
%$%?%..%%.%!-?=4&%$%?%..%%.%!!-?=5&%$%?%..%%.%!!!-?=6&%$%?%...%-?=7&%$%?%...%!-?=8
%$%?%...%!!-?=9&%$%?%...%!!!-?==&%$%?%...%%.%-?=+&%$%?%...%%.%!-?=-&%$%?%...%%.%!!-?=^<
%$%?%...%%.%!!!-?=^>&%$%?%...%%..%-?=@&%$%?%...%%..%!-?=*&Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
%$%e=&For /l %%i in (97 1 122)Do (%$%"e=!e!^!"&Cmd/cExit %%i
%$%"?!e!?=!=ExitCodeASCII!"&For /f delims^= %%v in ('cmd/c%$%/A%%i-32')DO Cmd/cExit %%v
%$%"?!e!+?=!=ExitCodeASCII!")
%$%#=&%$%p=%%&%$%i=0&%$%"T[0]=%_: ="&Set/Ai+=1&Set "T[!i!]=%"
For /l %%i in (0 1 !i!)Do For /f "tokens=1 delims==" %%v in ('%$%T[%%i]')Do (IF defined # (Call %$%"#=!#:^^=^!!p!!%%~v!!p!")Else Call %$%"#=!p!!%%~v:^^=^!!p!")
Echo(!#:^^=!&Endlocal
```

How:

- assigns each command token as a variable with it's respective character.
- Split input on ??, assign each to a token array - T[#]
- Iterates through the array of command tokens, expands each to its value (character) and appends to the command line variable #

Notes:

- run from the command line, input is as taken as a command line argument.
- requires delayed expansion to be disable (default)

Comment: Can you use <s> and </s> to keep old scores

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, <s>191 161</s> 133 bytes

-30 Thanks Kaddath!
-28 Thanks tsh!

```
for e in input()[1:-1].split("??"):print(end={"!":chr(len(e)+96),"+":chr(len(e)+63),"-":('<>& ?!%/.:0123456789=+'*9)[len(e)]}[e[-1]])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hYzRCoIwGIXvfYr5Q7nltNSylGy9h3ghMlEYc9iCInp2S4TCMjpX53xwPnXVVSP9rsupTmqpzhqT1IsdL3NPStQaA2NAKIBRNi3iqJYojw1UUkFVUlQtFVxiTihPnxcD8Qsv8A1MiEHbSYmFHYUEKNhvEAY9cAZgHRdzxMzZ0o1Xnh@sN@F2FyX2/mClIoN7qjJiqLaWGumuA2Z@hLGpOt59cUbrl2Li@IVfcFD@0zF4AA)

### Explanation

(Will update this later)

Ungolfed:

```python
a = input[1:-1].split("??") # Get every part
t = "" # Output string
for e in a: # Iterates over a
 f,l,p=chr,len(e),e[-1] # They are used many times, this is for shorter code
 exec({
  "!":"t+=f(l+96)",                       # if ends with "!", get the l+96 -th ASCII char
  "+":"t+=f(l+63)",                       # ends with "+", get the l+63 -th
  "-":"t+='@*& ?!%/.:0123456789=+<>'[l]"  # hard-coded string
 }[p])
print t # print the result
```

Comment: I don't know much Python but I think you can golf this code more by removing some whitespace. The general rules for output also say that you can either output the result directly, or have a function that returns the result, so you're not obliged to output the result in a function if it's shorter to return it. I recommend also [Tips for golfing in Python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/54/90841)

Comment: [example in 161 bytes that directly prints the result (without function) an removed whitespace](https://tio.run/##hYzRCoIwGIXvfYr5Q7nltNSylGy9h3ghMlEYc9iCInp2S4TCMjpX53xwPnXVVSP9rsupTmqpzhqT1IsdL3NPStQaA2NAKIBRNi3iqJYojw1UUkFVUlQtFVxiTihPnxcD8Qsv8A1MiEHbSYmFHYUEKNhvEAY9cAZgHRdzxMzZ0o1Xnh@sN@F2FyX2/mClIoN7qjJiqLaWGumuA2Z@hLGpOt59cUbrl2Li@IVfcFD@0zF4AA)

Comment: `print` is 1 byte shorter than `return`, yes.@Kaddath And thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Yes I checked and your code seems not compatible with implicit return, but if you print directly you don't need the function then

Comment: 133 bytes by switch to Python 3, remove `exec`, and some line breaks: `for e in input()[1:-1].split("??"):print(end={"!":chr(len(e)+96),"+":chr(len(e)+63),"-":('<>& ?!%/.:0123456789=+'*9)[len(e)]}[e[-1]])`

Comment: It may also be 133 byte if switch to function submission: [`lambda x:''.join({"!":chr(len(e)+96),"+":chr(len(e)+63),"-":('<>& ?!%/.:0123456789=+'*9)[len(e)]}[e[-1]]for e in x[1:-1].split("??"))`](https://tio.run/##hcrhCoIwFIbhW5mD2llLSy3Lke1CTMJq4sKmmJERXbsJShCBnV/ne3iLR5Xm2mmSYNdk8eVwilHNCbHOudLwxAbmx7SETGqQlPkenWL2RZ7bkok5kM12jIQxmll8bjvuYumt1n7AyMSnYddGr1CGph1FSV4iiZRGdWjzFqxrkakKsBCY0qYola4ggTK@75UubhXQVoXRHxPdKz7yb/Vg/uhgPhx162OmeAM)

Answer (score 2):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), <s>164</s> 158 bytes

```
func[s][r: copy""parse s[any["?"(n: 0)any["!"(n: n + 1)]["+?"(c: to sp 64 +
n)|"-?"(c: pick"& ?!%/.:0123456789=+-<>@*"n)|"?"(c: to sp 96 + n)](append r c)]]r]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hYzLDoIwEEX3fMXQREMlKCqiNGr9BrdNF6SUhJiUpuCCqN@OPBIjinFW99yZOUYm9VkmjFspgTq9KsEKzgwBkesKIR2bQkLBYlUxRJGjCPi4A7sDBS4sMWfIbZaCQJlDoSEMwLUUviOvb3UmLmgK1J4s5sRfrtbBJtzuooPr7Y@nGWov39@jsLEqzJ1Ya6kSMCAw54bX2mSqhBRu1P4YSsfikNvgDeiXYuTxq36VvfKfjj7qJw)

### Old, non-Parse solution, 169 bytes

```
func[s][r: copy""foreach c extract next split s"?"2[d: length? c append r switch
to 1 last c[33[to sp 96 + d]43[to sp 63 + d]45[pick"& ?!%/.:0123456789=+-<>@*"d - 1]]]r]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hYzBisIwFEX3/YprQBdKdWq1apkxfsNsQxYlSW2xpCHJMDPIfHusyAhqxbd43HN571glw6eSjEdljlB@acEcZzaHaM0vIWVrVSEqCKgfbwvhobsAZ5q624SSOZM5GqX3vqLdVWGM0hIW7rv2oop8iwRN4TwES1PWoTPYZJhA8sU/Z@mFl8zU4kBGoIPhbJq/JfN0scxW683HJH7f7sZEIkbCObc8GFtrjxJHOrgbSvviLZ9DfEPPFD2PD/W1vChf6ehfOAE)

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 125 bytes

```javascript
s=>s.split`?`.map(a=>(b=a.length)?(z=a.slice(-1))==`-`?'& ?!%/.:0123456789=+-<>@*'[b-2]:Buffer([b+(63*z==`+`||96)]):a).join``
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hYzRCoIwAEV/pR7KTdlKLStpLvoNCTZtK2M5cdaD@O9mBIFldJ/uuXDPhd@5ScusqFCuj6KVpDUkMtgUKqsYZfjKC8BJBBLCsRL5qTpDCuoOjMpSAZALISEMMWpNR3Q8meFw7nr@Yhms1hvioG20s604Qd4h3N@kFCWIEwcEvl13L4c1zSaABxhyiC86yxlrU50brQRW@gQksOj4I5QO1T4/C@rRL8XA8Wt@jy/lPx21IGwf)

````javascript
s.split`?`         splits the string at the char ?, results in an array
.map(a=>           pass item n in array to function and replace item with the return
    (b=a.length)?...            if a is not empty do ...
        a.slice(-1)==`-`?...     if last char in a is - do ...
            '& ?!%/.:0123456789=+-<>@*'[b-2]    get character at index
        :         else
        Buffer(b+(63*z==`+`||96))   character from code
    :a                 else return a
).join``            array to string

```
````

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 44 bytes

```
⭆⪪Ｓ?⎇№ι!§⎇№ι-”‴"μ⮌w7Ｌ⁴Vp#ωδk4θO(”⎇№ι+αβ⊖№ι!ι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRCO4BEil@yYWaAQX5GSWaHjmFZSWQAQ1NHUUlOyVgGRIalFeYlGlhnN@KVBLJlBYESTsWOKZl5JaoYEprQuSVlJTsFdU1dezMjA0MjYxNTO3sLTV1rWxc9BSwmakNkhPoo5CkiaQdklNLkrNTc0rSU1BtRUkmQkkrf//t1dEA/b22JiofBBDF4WHywgsGjGE4YIQIwkZZ/9ftywHAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
⭆⪪Ｓ?
```

Split the input on `?`s and map over each substring.

```
⎇№ι!
```

If this substring contains a `!`, then...

```
§⎇№ι-”‴"μ⮌w7Ｌ⁴Vp#ωδk4θO(”⎇№ι+αβ⊖№ι!
```

... count the number of `!`s and use this to index into either the compressed string of non-alphabetic characters or the upper or lower case alphabet depending on whether there is a `-` or `+` or not.

```
ι
```

Otherwise leave the substring unchanged.